# GRPC connection state listeners Java

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I'm interesting - could i have some notifies about connection/disconnection events for GRPC client/server?
Now, when client terminates connection to server i'm getting exception on server:

```
июн 22, 2018 9:34:47 AM io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport notifyTerminated
INFO: Transport failed
java.io.IOException: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1108)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Exception translate: "The remote host forcibly broke the existing connection"

I'm interesting, how could i manage connect/disconnect events both for client and server?

Maybe there is some ways to attach my own listener to client or server? From sources i didn't figure out how to make it

Comment: I don't see any _exception_ listed. I just see a log statement. Was there anything else logged?

Comment: Yes, i added full log info to first post.

Answer (score 2):

gRPC does not provide, on purpose, connection-level notifications. You don't mention your use-case, but the vast majority of use-cases are broken by load balancing, proxies, and gRPC's reconnect logic.

There is a way to determine whether a Channel is healthy, via `ManagedChannel.getState(false)`, which can be useful to provide a UI for users or to tell other clients the server is not healthy. Other use cases should be built on individual RPCs.

Comment: So, if i wan't to get notification about channel disconnect - i need to implement polling with {ManagedChannel.getState(false)}? No other ways to be notified about channel state change as soon as possible?

Comment: You should really explain what high-level goal you're trying to accomplish; you're use case. `ManagedChannel.notifyWhenStateChanged` can notify you when `getState` changes

Comment: If my grpc client service doesnt connected to server, i need to change service behavior to "default". Assume that i have a service which validates user payments. If service doesn't connected to server i need at least to log user payment validation request, and also, i need to check what happened with "server service". And i want to get notifications about "server service" shutdown as soon as possible, not when some user will try to make payment.